# Why hadoop `FileSystem.delete` return a boolean

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I'm confused about this API. If the deletion failed, shouldn't it throw an exception to explain the reason? Why does it return a boolean to tell us if deletion success or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 methods in [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) class which are `delete` and `deleteonexit`. These 2 methods are interesting in normal java programming language [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?java/io/File.html) as well. 
If FileSystem  handle is not closed while `delete` with one of the client. Then `delete` returns `false`. No need to throw exception.

In that case in finally block we can use `deleteOnExit` so that jvm will mark and delete the `FileSystem` once its terminated.

```
abstract boolean    delete(Path f, boolean recursive)
Delete a file.
boolean deleteOnExit(Path f)
Mark a path to be deleted when FileSystem is closed.
```

Hope this helps